# ¿Cómo hacer consultas en una tabla llamada por load en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero mostrar datos de 2 tablas de mi bd, lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```php
public function getReservasTable()
{
    $reservas = Reserva::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
    $reservas = $reservas->load('matricula.cliente','actividad');        
    return response()->json($reservas);
}
```

Usando load para llamar a la tabla actividad, ya que es una tabla anidada, lo que quiero saber es como hacerle una consulta a esa tabla, ya que tengo que mostrar el registro de esa tabla del ultimo mes o etc, les dejo todo el código, espero me puedan ayudar.

---

Este es el modelo Reserva, donde llamo a la tabla actividad:

```
class Reserva extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reservas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'id_matricula',
        'id_actividad',
        'estado'
    ];

    public function actividad(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Actividad::class, 'id_actividad');
    }
```

Y este seria el modelo de Actividad:

```php
class Actividad extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'actividads';

    protected $fillable = [
        
        'id',
        'title',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'tipo_actividad',
        'color',
        'hora_inicio',
        'hora_fin',
    ];
```

Comment: Puedes revisar bien las relaciones pues `$this->belongsTo(Actividad::class, 'id_actividad');` no deberias cambiar el identificador por omision pues laravel lo hace solo. Ademas revisa el modelo de `Actividad` pues tienes un error en esta linea `protected $table = 'actividads';` tienes una `s` de mas.

Comment: 'actividads' así se llama la tabla en mi base de datos, no tengo ningun error, se muestran los datos, lo que quiero es hacer una consulta a la tabla

Comment: Considera editar por favor y agregar que has intentado al momento